# Excel FILTER & COUNTIF

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

Currently, the formula in cell F7 is: `=FILTER(C3:C7, COUNTIF($F$3:$F$4, $B$3:$B$7))`

However, that formula can only return "Pen" and "Paper". But now I would like it to be when cell `G3` is "Price" then 5 and 2 will be returned; if cell `G3` is "Item" then "Pen" and "Paper" will be returned

May I know how should I modify the formula in cell `F7`?

You can have a look at the screenshot attached below to understand my question better. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `=IF(G3="Price",FILTER(D3:D7, COUNTIF($F$3:$F$4, $B$3:$B$7)),FILTER(C3:C7, COUNTIF($F$3:$F$4, $B$3:$B$7)))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=FILTER(FILTER($B$3:$D$7,$B$2:$D$2=$G$3),COUNTIF($F$3:$F$4, $B$3:$B$7))`
It first filters the range to where the column header equals the value in `G3`, then it filters that column with your countif results.